# Adding a basic authentication handler as an additional handler into an asp.net 6 default identity page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an asp.net 6 website which uses Default Identity with various external authentication handlers and password authentication. Additionally we have the requirement, that the site allows BASIC authentication headers for some legacy access clients.
I created a Basic authentication handler and registered it. This works fine, as long as I only use this as the primary handler  (`AddAuthentication(“myScheme”).AddScheme<MyBasicHandler>("myScheme")`).
However as soon as I want to use other authentication schemes, I have the following issues:

- The basic scheme is shown in the list of the external login providers
- When activating the basic scheme, nothing happens, it always goes back to the login page
- The handler is never called. If a BASIC auth header is available, it is ignored

For the last problem, I suspect to have to register a middleware, which checks for the BASIC header and then calls the authentication scheme manually. Is this right?
What about the first two problems? Am I on the complete wrong track on how to do this? Is it wrong to register the handler via the `AddScheme`-extension?

Comment: If I get the question right, we're intended to support multiple authentication schemes right ? If that's the case, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70153302/dynamically-chose-authentication-scheme-in-asp-net-core-wep-api/70154322#70154322) answers what we need ?

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks, this looks exactly like the solution to the last problem. Sadly, it will become next week before I can test it for real (currently working on a project of another client). Probably, it will still be shown in the  list of the external providers, do you have also a solution for this or do I have for scaffold the concerned default identity page(s) and the change the list manually?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have solution for that one as I also hasn't encounter that situation yet. As I usually built login screen(with external login provider options) on SPA app and then redirect to server later.